# selecting few lines together in a group from text files

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a long text file with 3500 lines. The contents of the file is some thing below:

```
 Iteration 26
 WSSR        : 2.16978           delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : -5.96505e-05
 delta(WSSR) : -0.000129428      limit for stopping : 1e-05
 lambda   : 1.92367e-12

resultant parameter values

A               = 0.152297
B               = 22009.9
/

 Iteration 27
 WSSR        : 2.16978           delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : -6.95237e-07
 delta(WSSR) : -1.50851e-06      limit for stopping : 1e-05
 lambda   : 1.92367e-13

resultant parameter values

A               = 0.152268
B               = 22018.5

After 27 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 2.16978
rel. change during last iteration : -6.95237e-07

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 15996
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 0.0116467
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 0.000135645

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================

A               = 0.152268         +/- 0.0003536    (0.2322%)
B               = 22018.5          +/- 73.18        (0.3324%)


correlation matrix of the fit parameters:

               A      B      
A               1.000 
B              -0.712  1.000 
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 3072
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 4608
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 6912
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 10368
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 15552
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 23328


 Iteration 0
 WSSR        : 92.7915           delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : 0
 delta(WSSR) : 0                 limit for stopping : 1e-05
 lambda   : 0.000192367

initial set of free parameter values

C               = 1
D               = 1
***/

 Iteration 1
 WSSR        : 92.7561           delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : -0.000382419
 delta(WSSR) : -0.0354717        limit for stopping : 1e-05
 lambda   : 0.0192367

resultant parameter values

C               = 1.09786
D               = 1.4932
/

 Iteration 2
 WSSR        : 91.9873           delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : -0.00835736
 delta(WSSR) : -0.768771         limit for stopping : 1e-05
 lambda   : 0.00192367
```

I would like to select 6 specific lines together start from line **Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error** throughout the whole text file. This group of lines do not occur in periodic manner in the text file. Some times it occurs after 10 lines or 30 lines.

I can think of grep command. But I have experience using it selecting only specific lines with specific words. Soemthing like

```
grep "Final set of parameters"
```

But is there any options need to add to achieve what I need?

How I can go about this?

Comment: But then, which lines do you expect as output? The 6 after "Final set of ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 grep -A6 'Final set of parameters' file
```

gives:

```
kent$  grep -A6 'Final set of parameters' f
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================

A               = 0.152268         +/- 0.0003536    (0.2322%)
B               = 22018.5          +/- 73.18        (0.3324%)
```

Comment: `sed -ne '/Final set of parameters/,+6p' file` would be another (although slightly more typing) option...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `awk`

```
awk '/Final set of parameters/ {f=6} f && f-- '
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================

A               = 0.152268         +/- 0.0003536    (0.2322%)
B               = 22018.5          +/- 73.18        (0.3324%)
```